# Focus previous tab/window when closing current

Tags: vim-windows, tabbed-user-interface

I tend to open multiple tabs in vim and multiple windows within a tab.

I have a habit of traversing the code in a tree format - I open a tag in a new tab, so that my current view of the window remains unchanged. I can simply close the newly opened tab/window to resume to my previous view.

Consider a case where I have window `A` focused. I open a new split as window `B`. Now, when I close window `B`, it should focus the earlier window `A`. Currently, it always focuses the window on left side of `B`.

Similarly, for tab close case, it always selects the tab on the right side of tab being closed.

Is there a way to keep track of the tab/window opening sequence in vim? Then I can trace back the sequence while closing the tab/windows...
Or better, is there a vim `set` command option or an internal variable that handles this automatically?

Comment: You can use `WinLeave` and `WinEnter` to maintain a stack of windows in the order you visit them.  But maintaining the stack directly would be a pain in the rear, since (1) windows are per-tab, and (2) their IDs get re-allocated.  You could get around that by creating your own unique IDs for each window, store them in `w:` variables, and put _those_ in the stack.  It would probably work eventually, but it would still be as robust as `autocmd`s.  Probably a reasonable idea for a plugin, too.

Comment: ^^ part1 is fine, because that's what I would want - I need to record the window opening order to be tab specific.Part2 is where I was struggling. If there are windows "1 2 3 4" and we open a window between 3 & 4, it will become #4 and #4 will be re-numbered as #5. Probably I could add a numbering system parallel to `winnr()` & store that as `w:winnr2`...

Comment: @anishsane: Note that this problem of windows ID should be solved in Vim 8 [which should be released in about 2 weeks](https://ossnews.net/s/doodca/vim_8_pre-announcement): The change list announce that windows [will have unique IDs](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt#L116-L120) I think that it will allow you to maintain the stack more easily.

Comment: Oh cool! I was trying to write a vimscript using winenter/winleave autocmd plus the parallel numbering scheme I mentioned. But if it is going to be solved soon, then I don't need the parallel numbering scheme... :-)

Comment: Wrote a script: http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9288/2749 Using my parallel numbering scheme for now, so that it remains vim7 compatible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written the script for this purpose.
It can be downloaded as vimball based plugin from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=5430.

```
Installation details:
$ wget http://www.vim.org/scripts/download_script.php?src_id=24462 -O FocusPrevious.vmb
$ vim FocusPrevious.vmb

Within vim:
:source %
:q

Restart vim
```

Comment: Most likely, I would release a vim8 version of this script, that takes advantages of [winid](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt#L116) and newly added [TabNew / WinNew / TabClosed / Winclosed autocmd events](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt#L348). That will make the script much cleaner.

Comment: can you make this installable using package managers like pathogen or vundle?

Comment: `vimball` is one of the package installers.

Comment: @JohnFredFadrigalan somebody forked it on GH, all fine here https://github.com/viecks/focus-previous thanks anishsane!

Answer (score 1):

For the windows you could use a function which get the number of the current window, goes to the previous one and close the window of which you got the number earlier. Something like this:

```
function CloseAndGoToPreviousW()
    let prevWin = winnr()
    execute "wincmd p"
    execute prevWin . "wincmd q"
endfunction
```

You can then call the function directly or create a mapping to call it:

```
nnoremap <key> :call CloseAndGoToPreviousW()<CR>
```

Based on that I think you can do the same with the buffers with [`:h tabpagenr()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#tabpagenr()) and [`:h :tabclose`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html#:tabclose).

Comment: `wincmd p` only works to toggle between 2 windows, not a sequence of windows. So, if I open windows A->B->C, then closing C should focus B & closing B should focus A. with `wincmd p` based solution, first part will work, but second part will not work. I should have mentioned that I had tried it.

Comment: @anishsane: Oh indeed I hadn't thought about more complex use cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Similarly, for tab close case, it always selects the tab on the right side of tab being closed.

<strike>These two lines force vim to go to the left on tabclose and closing a buffer will not close the window. They don't answer OP's question, but they answer the similar question that led me here.</strike>

The TabClosed autocommand now works for an arbitrary last tab. I'll leave the buffer command as is, though I may fix it later.

```
" Keep a list of the most recent two tabs.
let g:tablist = [1, 1]
autocmd TabLeave * let g:tablist[0] = g:tablist[1]
autocmd TabLeave * let g:tablist[1] = tabpagenr()
" When a tab is closed, return to the most recent tab.
" The way vim updates tabs, in reality, this means we must return
" to the second most recent tab.
autocmd TabClosed * exe "normal " . g:tablist[0] . "gt"

cnoremap bd<cr> b#<bar>bd#<cr>
```

Comment: Not the left tab; the last focussed tab.

Comment: @anishsane The tab commands should now work as described in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Vim8 or Vim9 with the following snippet in ~/.vimrc works for me.

```
autocmd TabClosed * tabprevious
```

Comment: That is not necessarily the last focussed tab. But my fault for using the wrong word in the title.